# Spreadsheet - Google App Script [string split function]

Tags: arrays, split, google-apps-script

Just wanted to verify some thought regarding split function. I have constructed a simple code.

```
var array1 = [{}];
var string1 = "A, B, C, D";

array1 = string1.split(",");
```

The problem is based on this kind of coding for example in flash. The string1 will split all `","` then transfers it to the array1 in this format `["A","B","C", "D"]`. Is this kind of concept similar to Google Spreadsheet - GAS? If yes can you site some example? Thanks a lot guys.

P.S: When I tried splitting the `","` it only returns the value `"A B C D"` as a single element.

Thanks,
Nash :)

Comment: string.split() returns an array. The exact format on how you see is irrelevant because ultimately it is an array of 4 elements - the four elements being 
A
 B
 C
 D
Note the spaces.

Comment: Thanks! Srik, I was just clarifying the concept of split() on GAS, now it seems to be more clear.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your code should definitely work, I just ran this with a breakpoint on `Logger.log(array1);`  The debugger shows it as an array, and the log logs it as: `[A, B, C, D]`.  Note, that to get the output you wanted I had to add a space to the split to get: `string1.split(", ");`

```
function myFunction() {
  var array1 = splitTest();
  Logger.log(array1);
}

function splitTest() {
  var array1 = [{}];
  var string1 = "A, B, C, D";

  array1 = string1.split(", ");
  return array1
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Brandon Shults for clarifying this and providing a clean way of coding it in order... It really means a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

**J.Doe**, I cannot submit a comment either, but your problem here is that if you get the value from a form, its type can be an object instead of a string. Hence you are getting the error of no function in object.

You can go around this by converting those objects to strings this way:

```js
objectPretendingString = JSON.stringify(objectPretendingString) //becomes a string
```